How would you connect multiple large prints permanently together?
I have 3D printed the Operator Sledge's (Rainbow Six Siege) sledgehammer for a cosplay convention out of PLA filament and want to permanently affix the different shaft pieces.

Hi, and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please add photos of the shaft pieces. Ideally the piece models have an interlocking structure and you can epoxy or superglue (Cyanoacrylate) them together. Without details it will be guessing how the parts can be connected. PLA bonds very well to superglue. I guess your answer can be found in What is the best glue for the task of assembling a 3D printed part with other materials? or in answer What glues for bonding printed PLA to injection-molded plastic?.

Are you asking for help with adhesives to stick a part that someone else made the print files for, or with altering a file to make it easier to fit together, or a combination of the above?
